# Disable unused Subversion features

Tags: svn

My organization uses Subversion for source control as usual, but there's been an interest in using Subversion to store non-software related documents - specifically, engineering drawings.

The users would be engineers who need a secure and versioned repository for their technical drawings. These would be binary files, so we're aware it wouldn't be the most efficient use of Subversion. Also they won't need branching, tagging, merging, etc. - just the versioning capabilities.

The users aren't software engineers, and this will be their first use of Subversion, and - well, engineers like to take things apart. I'd like to prevent them from breaking anything. What I'd like to know is whether I can turn off, at the server, the features they won't be using, so that nobody will be tempted to *play*...

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it on server (except "recompile" option), but you *can* prepare minified client-side GUI (if Windows)

Comment: Yeah, we're using Windows. Is there such a GUI that I can use?

Comment: I think TortoiseSVN lets you customize the contextual menu - you can't really disable features but you can certainly hide them.